# Entity Framework many to many with parent/child table

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, parent-child

I am trying to develop a query that seeks parents in a table where the fields are parent and child, using lambda syntax or query syntax.

My model is basically 
**Entities**
EntityID
Name
Age
EntityType

**EntitiesRelation**
EntityParentID [PK, FK, EntityID]
EntityChildID  [PK, FK, EntityID]

I know I cannot access the EntitiesRelation table directly (because it is a Join table). I have other queries with join tables, but this case, I couldn't resolve until now.

Comment: Why you can't acces it? You should have two navigation properties named EntitiesRelations and EntitiesRelations1 (if you did not changed their names).

Comment: What is showed to me is: Entities1 and Entities11

Comment: Please cease signing your posts. I've seen you do it today on other Stack Exchange sites also, despite the fact that a guy on GameDev instructed you not to _two years ago_. Also, since SO is not a helpdesk, asking for "tips" is not quite on topic. This is a repository/database of concrete questions and concrete answers about programming languages and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have two navigation properties, Entities1 and Entities11 as you stated, one belongs to the relationship as parent and the other as child.

Look at the designer to which one corresponds each and name them "Parent" and "Children" and you are ready.

Comment: Really thanks Man! 'll try to change/edit this convention because it is too confusing.

Comment: Yes, it's really awful, I also hate it :D